# Artifactory not using specified home directory

Tags: tomcat8, artifactory

I'm currently hosting Artifactory on `Tomcat8/JDK1.8`.

If I check the system info screen, I can see that files are being written in `/u01/usr/share/tomcat8/.artifactory/`

However, in the servlet configuration in `bin/setenv.sh`, I specified the Artifactory home to be somewhere else:

`-DARTIFACTORY_HOME=/u01/opt/artifactory`

Then, I discovered in the [docs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF20/Deploying+the+WAR+File), it's supposed to be lower case:

`-Dartifactory_home=/u01/opt/artifactory`

I rebooted Tomcat after the changes and the path targetted is still `/u01/usr/share/tomcat8/.artifactory`. The folder is owned by the user running Tomcat as well.

Why isn't it using the specified home dir?

Answer (score 0):

This seems a bit old but for others that struggle with it, you need to set an Environment variable `ARTIFACTORY_HOME` in your Tomcat startup script not a System variable via `-D` parameter.

**Linux**

```
set ARTIFACTORY_HOME=/pathto/your/artifactory
```

**Windows**

```
"set ARTIFACTORY_HOME=C:\path to your/artifactory"
```

*Notice the quotes for Windows*

**System properties** are set on the Java command line using the -Dpropertyname=value syntax. They can also be added at runtime using System.setProperty(String key, String value) or via the various System.getProperties().load() methods.
To get a specific system property you can use System.getProperty(String key) or System.getProperty(String key, String def).

**Environment variables** are set in the OS, e.g. in Linux export HOME=/Users/myusername or on Windows SET WINDIR=C:\Windows etc, and, unlike properties, may not be set at runtime.
To get a specific environment variable you can use System.getenv(String name).